# Is there an R function to convert non-standard scientific notation?

Tags: r, scientific-notation

I'm presently working with a dataset (made from a biostatistics research project) which denotes expression ranks in a value such as "1.00e3" rather than "1.00e+03" which seems to confuse the system when ranking. Does anyone have any ideas as to how to work within the data frame to force it to convert "e" notations to standard form? I have already tried scipen and formatC.

Comment: Try with `options(scipen = 999)`

Comment: `1.00e3` is still considered as standard. What do you mean by `non-standard`?

Comment: `as.numeric("1.00e3")` seems to work just fine. Can you create some sort of [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and the code you are running that makes it clear what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to rank a character vector numerically.  Which can indeed go awry. The trick is to convert to numeric for ranking.

```
x = c("1.00e3", "1.00e+04", "1.0e05")
sort(x)
# "1.00e+04" "1.00e3"   "1.0e05"  
sort(as.numeric(x))
# 1e+03 1e+04 1e+05
```

If you *really* need the values in character format rather than numeric (which seems unlikely), you can do

```
format(as.numeric(x), scipen=999)
# [1] "1e+03" "1e+04" "1e+05"
```